# PHP 5 Framework, which is the best for a networking site with a lof of API and jQuery

Tags: php, frameworks

I know this is the type of question that I can easily find all over the web. But my question needs a much more specific answer than the ones I have found while browsing.

I am supposed to build a Social Networking website with a LOT of features.

Just to name some of them:

Internal Search Engine

Integration of a LOT of APIs (Google, Facebook, Twitter etc.. )

Multi-Language

Many jQuery implementations

Easy to integrate with mobile applications

Easy to create internal and external API

I was taking a look to Zend and Yii, but I am not sure which one is better, or if there is another one that is going to be better for me.

I need something that has a LOT of documentation, that is well supported, and that has at least an established name (do not provide unknown frameworks that you work on or you have worked on, please no spam here, thanks)

Please help me :)

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why is it that you need a framework for this at all? If your site is going to be used by a lot of people, the overhead of a framework could be a killer.

Comment: Because I would like to use OOP. I am totally new to object oriented PHP and maybe a framework could help me in this case. Do you really advise to build everything from the scratch? I am a little worried, you know :)

Comment: I really do - It's scary at first but to be completely honest you will get a much better grasp of OOP if you were to learn it yourself, rather than learning a framework's conventions. Zend is the worst for this as it's naming is terrible and it's generally bloated (people will of course disagree with me but..). Of course it's completely your decision and I'm only 1 opinion, but for both learning and optimisation purposes, I'd recommend doing everything from scratch :)

Comment: Thanks for your advise. The only concern I have is that I will need about ten years to write everything alone ahah. Thanks again. And I will for sure take in mind your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to reiterate, you're new to programming yet you're taking on a challenge such as building a social network, one that has "a lot of features" at that as you say. Then you move on asking which framework is the best.. that kind of question is without context, completely.

If you are new to OOP, then learn what it is, don't use it just because you "want to", that's a stupid reason.
Then check out what framework suits you. There tons of frameworks out there. Some are fast, some aren't as fast. Some use methodologies that might fit your way of thinking, some don't.

Key point is - learn to swim before you go to the Olympics. And then check which framework suits your way of coding and thinking.

Comment: I am a PHP developer "in the old way" and I am now moving to OOP. I am learning OOP by reading tutorial etc.. So, for sure, I will learn OOP before starting this project. I am just curious to know which framework (if one exists) will help me saving time for all the things I have to realize.

Comment: And then I'll repeat - how can anyone tell you that? All of the frameworks have their quirks, advantages and disadvantages. All of them are MVC based, a concept that requires you to have OOP understanding - which you don't know (yet). If someone tells you to go with Zend and in 2 years you find out that Symfony fits you better, then what? Learn how to **properly** use OO with PHP (and that WILL take time), then worry about frameworks. Step by step, don't run before you walk :)

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I`ve found a short and clear post about PHP frameworks http://www.quora.com/Do-you-Think-Yii-Framework-is-the-best
I guess it can be helpful